# How to load an image to the imageView from a URL?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uiimage

I have the following code in my `ViewController.swift` class:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!

    var newImage : UIImage?

    let imgURL = NSURL(string : DemoURLs.photoURL)

    func fetchImage(){
        if let url = imgURL{
           let imageData = NSData(contentsOfURL: url)

              if imageData != nil{
                 newImage  = UIImage( data: imageData! )
              } else {
                newImage = nil
            }
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        imageView.image = newImage
    }
}
```

The `demoURLs.swift` file has a simple struct like this:

```
import Foundation

struct DemoURLs{
    static var photoURL = " http://science-all.com/images/wallpapers/image/image-6.jpg "
}
```

When I run this in the simulator I get a plain white screen.

Comment: you've never run fetchImage(), have you?

Answer (score 1):

There are three problems:

1. You url contain whitespace at the beginning and end of the string (so it starts as `<Space>http://s...`, but should be `http://s...`)
2. If you developing for iOS 9, it block `http` request for security reason. You could disable it by going `Info.plist` file, adding `App Transport Security Settings` key and adding another key inside it - `Allow Arbitrary Loads` with `YES` value. Should look something like this:

[image]

3. You should call `fetchImage()` in  `viewDidLoad()`, just before you set image `imageView.image = newImage`

Comment: @EricD yep, added, thanks :)